# Densely packed tree of signals

Tags: haskell, functor, mutable, unboxing, zipper

I collect realtime signals, compute derived signals and store both raw and derived data
in a circular buffer, so I hold only last million of samples.

Sometimes I need to serialize current values for all signals. So I need something like:

```
type D0 a = M.Map SignalType D1

data D1 a = D1 
    { foo :: M.Map DoorType a
    , bar :: D2 a
    , baz :: a
    }

data D2 = D2 
    {
        quux :: a
    ,   zoo :: a
    }

data MyData = D0 SignalBuffer 

data CurrentSignals = D0 SignalValue
```

`SignalBuffer` is a sequence of `SignalValue`. It can be an unboxed array of floats. Haskell can derive `Functor` instances for me, so I can use `fmap` to fetch last `SignalValue` from every `SignalBuffer` and pass the structure to `Aeson` to serialize.

How do I implement a circular buffer API for `SignalBuffer` so I can push new values to all the buffers when new ticks arrive? I'd like to conserve memory, so I think I have to use unboxed arrays. Is it advantageous to use mutable unboxed arrays (`STUArray`?) so array updates don't pile up in memory? Is it possible to use mutable arrays in this setting at all? I'm ready to change `MyData` and `CurrentSignals` to whatever does the job.

I know how to implement circular buffers, the question is how to elegantly apply the updates to `MyData`.

I'm thinking of something like

```
type UpdateFunc a = MyData -> SignalValue -> Modifier SignalBuffer

updateAllBuffers :: D0 UpdateFunc -> Modifier MyData
```

Some signals are "convolutions" of other signals (not real convolutions, but a similar kind of processing). To update a buffer for a signal I need to access buffers of other signals - that's why UpdateFunc accepts `MyData` and `SignalValue` and returns a buffer modification function.

`updateAllBuffers` then "zips" `D0 UpdateFunc` and `MyData` to get new `MyData`.

Of course I'm ready to use whatever `Modifier` fits my task - it can be a function, a monadic value etc.

Comment: Do you need to read from just the tail of the buffer, or from possibly any location within it?  I wrote about some related work at http://johnlato.blogspot.sg/2012/03/pure-delay-lines.html; if you need random access the best-performing solution I know of is to essentially write it like you would in C, with mutable data in IO.

Comment: The question is how to design the API. Haskell is not C, so beautiful generic solutions to bulk updates should be possible even with monadic  approach. I cannot use `Seq` because of space overhead, but sequential reading back from the tail should be enough.

Comment: I expect you'll end up with something like `type Modifier a = a -> IO a`, but for now I think if you do that `updateAllBuffers` will have to process your maps through a list conversion.  That's not necessarily bad, but maybe somebody else will have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not entirely understand what you are trying to do with the code above, but you can use `IOVector` from [Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Mutable.html#t:IOVector) for a high-performance array to make a circular buffer:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.IORef (IORef, newIORef, readIORef, writeIORef)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (IOVector, Unbox)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as V

data CircularBuffer a where
  CircularBuffer :: Unbox a =>
    { start :: IORef Int -- index for getting an element
    , end   :: IORef Int -- index for putting an element
    , array :: IOVector a
    } -> CircularBuffer a 

newCircularBuffer :: (Unbox a) => Int -> IO (CircularBuffer a)
newCircularBuffer size = CircularBuffer <$> newIORef 0 <*> newIORef 0 <*> V.new size 

putCircularBuffer :: Unbox a => a -> CircularBuffer a -> IO ()
putCircularBuffer newEndValue (CircularBuffer _start end array) = do
  endIndex <- readIORef end
  V.write array endIndex newEndValue
  writeIORef end $! (endIndex + 1) `mod` V.length array

getCircularBuffer :: Unbox a => CircularBuffer a -> IO a
getCircularBuffer (CircularBuffer start _end array) = do
  startIndex <- readIORef start
  startValue <- V.read array startIndex
  writeIORef start $! (startIndex + 1) `mod` V.length array
  pure startValue
```

You can then make a map like function (it would be IO though) that applies a function to every item in the `CircularBuffer`'s array.